# Get the eclipse version on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos

How can I get the version of eclipse(x32 or x64 ) in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `file` command to get more information about a file:

```
$ file /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview 
/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

As you can see, `/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview` (the executable file for Preview) is both 32- and 64-bit. Substitute the path to Eclipse’s executable and you should be able to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Run Activity Monitor while Eclipse is running. There is a column called 'Kind' which shows whether an app is running in 32 or 64-bit mode.